# Multiple layers with dc.js series charts

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm struggling to get a dc.js plot to work. The data object contains 2 value fields, and I need to designate `val` to *scatterPlot* and `smooth` to *lineChart*.  Example below and [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/2c6ovyht/).

```
<div id="series-chart"></div>

<style>div{ display: inline; }</style>

<script>

var datum = [
  {date: "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z", val: 0, smooth: 3, type: "set1"},
  {date: "2018-01-02T00:00:00Z", val: 7, smooth: 4, type: "set1"},
  {date: "2018-01-03T00:00:00Z", val: 1, smooth: 6, type: "set1"},
  {date: "2018-01-04T00:00:00Z", val: 4, smooth: 8, type: "set1"},
  {date: "2018-01-05T00:00:00Z", val: 8, smooth: 11, type: "set1"},
  {date: "2018-01-06T00:00:00Z", val: 15, smooth: 14, type: "set1"},
  {date: "2018-01-07T00:00:00Z", val: 12, smooth: 17, type: "set1"},
  {date: "2018-01-08T00:00:00Z", val: 20, smooth: 20, type: "set1"},
  {date: "2018-01-01T00:00:00Z", val: 15, smooth: 12, type: "set2"},
  {date: "2018-01-02T00:00:00Z", val: 10, smooth: 11, type: "set2"},
  {date: "2018-01-03T00:00:00Z", val: 14, smooth: 9, type: "set2"},
  {date: "2018-01-04T00:00:00Z", val: 7, smooth: 7, type: "set2"},
  {date: "2018-01-05T00:00:00Z", val: 12, smooth: 5, type: "set2"},
  {date: "2018-01-06T00:00:00Z", val: 8, smooth: 4, type: "set2"},
  {date: "2018-01-07T00:00:00Z", val: 8, smooth: 3, type: "set2"},
  {date: "2018-01-08T00:00:00Z", val: 5, smooth: 2, type: "set2"}

];
var data = crossfilter(datum);
var typeSeriesDimension = data.dimension(function(d){ return [d.type, new Date(d.date)]; });
var totalGroupRaw    = typeSeriesDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.val; });
var totalGroupSmooth = typeSeriesDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.smooth; });

var composite = dc.compositeChart("#series-chart");

composite
  .width(400)
  .height(400)
  .x(d3.time.scale().domain([new Date("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z"), new Date("2018-01-08T00:00:00Z")]))
  .dimension(typeSeriesDimension)
  .compose([
    dc.lineChart(composite)
      .dimension(typeSeriesDimension)
      .group(totalGroupSmooth)
      // .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[0];})
      .keyAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[1];})
      .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value;}) ,

    dc.scatterPlot(composite)
      .dimension(typeSeriesDimension)
      .group(totalGroupRaw)
      // .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[0];})
      .keyAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[1];})
      .valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value;})
  ])
  .legend(dc.legend().x(100).y(10).itemHeight(20).gap(5));


dc.renderAll();

</script>
```

The categorical colour mapping doesn't work without `seriesAccessor`, and uncommented these lines cause script to fail with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: dc.lineChart(...).dimension(...).group(...).seriesAccessor is not a function
```

Also the lines are for some reason I can't establish plotting in the wrong order.

All round fail. Any assistance much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dimension makes sense for the scatter plot, but it doesn't make sense for the line chart.

A line chart expects to have simple scalar keys like dates. But the scatter plot expects to have 2D keys like `[type, Date]`.

Luckily the composite chart doesn't really mind if its child charts use different dimensions.

So define a new time dimension and use that for the line chart's group:

```
var timeSeriesDimension = data.dimension(function(d) { return new Date(d.date);})
var totalGroupSmooth = timeSeriesDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.smooth; });
```

And drop your key and value accessors from the line chart, because the default behavior is fine now:

```
  //.keyAccessor(function(d) {return d.key[1];})
  //.valueAccessor(function(d) {return d.value;}) ,
```

As for `seriesAccessor`, that's only used with [dc.seriesChart](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.seriesChart.html), so I'm afraid it won't help you here. It's probably possible to combine a scatter plot with a series chart, because the series chart is just a specialization of the composite chart, but I haven't tried that - and I'd rather leave that for another question if you want to try that out.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The goal is simple - data points corresponding trend lines for data too noisy to visualise raw. I'll try and reformulate the question as you suggest when I have time.